# Basic: $1$ unit costs $\$10.00 $. Increases by $\$50 $ every unit. Total cost for $1000$ units?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The cost for $1$ car is $\$10.00$.
Every time you buy $1$, the cost increases by $\$50$.
What is the cost for $1000$ units.
If you have $10$ million dollars, how many units can you buy.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: For the record, `$` signs here are used in order to initiate math mode for writing fancy equations.  [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more information on how to type with $\LaTeX$ and MathJax.  If you wish for a dollar sign to appear like \$, then use a slash before it like `\$` in order to prevent it from entering math-mode.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
And this site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Also, generally currency symbols are written in front of numerical values.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- How much money do you spend if you purchase one unit?

You spend $10000$

- How much if you purchase two units?

You spend $10000+10050$

- Three?

$10000+10050+10100$

- Can you come up with a general pattern for if you want to purchase $n$ units?

> The $k^{th}$ unit costs $99950+50k$, so the total cost will be $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(99950+50k\right)$

What do you know about [triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) so that you can simplify the above summation?

Answer (score 0):

The cost for 11 car is $\$10.000$ Everytime you buy 11, the cost increases by $\$50$. What is the cost for 1000 units. IF you have 10 million dollars, how many units can you buy.

---

The cost of $x$ cars is $10000x+50\left(\frac{x\left(x+1\right)}{2}\right)$. So now our equation becomes:

$10000x+25x\left(x+1\right)\leq10000000$.

Plugging 1000 into the expression, the cost of 1000 cars is $\$35025000$.

And after solving the inequality, we find that we can produce 462 cars if we have $10 million.